# Why there is an extra UIView when adding an XIB view from the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uikit

I created a Tag view from XIB (see the document outline on the left) which contains only one subview which is a `UILabel`. The constraints set for the content view is its width and height should equal to the label, the label should use its intrinsic value.

[image]

I placed this Tag inside another view created from XIB, however, when I run the app there is an extra `UIView` underneath the Tag.

I do not understand what causes this additional one `UIView`. Everything describes above is done inside the Interface Builder, expect the file's owner is done inside the code editor.

[image] [image]

Large image here, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLFz7.jpg

```
@IBDesignable class DCCardTagView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCardTag: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: DCCardTagView.self)

        bundle.loadNibNamed(self.className, owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
}
```

Comment: show us screenshot of stack while debugging not the one from xib, it is probably this: `I placed this Tag inside another view created from XIB`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I updated the questions and added additional screenshots.

Comment: card tag view is some custom code? can you show that?

Comment: yes, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: `addSubview(contentView)` here main view is adding another one as subview, and `labelCardTag` on top of it. This is exactly like it looks like on screenshot

Comment: oh! that's why. Can I add `contentView` without invoking `addSubview`?

Comment: If you do that, you won't add your subview to the XIB's "default" `view`

Comment: Thank you Lu_ and Guilherme I think I figured out why there is an extra view. It is because there is a default one from XIB

Comment: Yeah, just like your `UIViewController`, you need to start at some point. Otherwise, you would need to manually create your "main" view, and then add all the stuff you want inside it.